# Why should I copy the array element by element and then append to list instead of appending directly?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, backtracking

In the below code I am printing all the subsets using backtracking.
I am printing the *res_list* at last.

```
res_list = [[], [13], [12], [12, 13]]
```

when I copy element by element of `subset_list` into a list and append to  `res_list` (line 4)

```
res_list = [[], [], [], []]
```

when I append `subset_list` to the `res_list` directly.(line 3)

I could not understand the why I need to copy element by element  of `subset_list` and then append to `res_list` instead of appending `subset_list` directly.

```
def print_subsets(arr, len_arr, cur_index, sub_set_list, res_list):
    if cur_index == len_arr:
        # res_list.append(sub_set_list)
        res_list.append([x for x in sub_set_list])
        return   


     # Include the element into the array list and pass to the next function call
        print_subsets(arr, len_arr, cur_index + 1, sub_set_list, res_list)
        sub_set_list.append(arr[cur_index])
        print_subsets(arr, len_arr, cur_index + 1, sub_set_list, res_list)
        sub_set_list.remove(arr[cur_index])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = []
    sub_list = []
    A = [12, 13]
    print_subsets(A, len(A), 0, sub_list, res)
    print(res)
```

Comment: You modify `sub_set_list` in place. If you use `res_list.append(sub_set_list)`, you're appending a reference to the same list, so it gets updated. When you use the list comprehension you're making a copy so it doesn't get updated.

Comment: Append it directly, change a value in `res_list` and check what happens to the values in `sub_set_list`.

Comment: You can simplify that to `res_list.append(sub_set_list.copy())`

Comment: Your `print_subsets` function will not execute at all in the example you have provided

Comment: `res_list.append(sub_set_list[:])` is another concise possibility

Answer (score 0):

`subset_list.copy()` and `subset_list[:]` both work.

The reference of the `subset_list` is appended directly.

To avoid it create a new list and append to the `res_list`.